# Export Org-mode Headers Level 4 or Above as Headers in Texinfo

Tags: org-mode, org-export, texinfo

I am writing software documentation using Org-mode, but I also want to export the result as a Texinfo file.  The process works well, however, Texinfo transforms level 4 headings into numbered lists instead of subsubsections, etc.  The documentation indicates to use `#+OPTIONS: num:6` exporting as subsubheadings, etc. instead of numbered lists for any header of level 6 or lower.  Has anybody run into this issue and know how to deal with it?  It is not a huge problem, but my INFO files would be easier to navigator with the proper layout.

Comment: Isn't  the option H:6 rather than num:6?

Comment: Humm, I will try your suggestion.  That is not what the org manual says, but I will try anything.  Will report back.

Comment: I can confirm that your H:6 suggestion worked.  However, the file has some compilation problems when compiling the texinfo file to info.  But, the heading export issue is solved using your recommendation.  Thanks much.

Comment: This is what I read in the manual: https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the org manual section "[Export settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html)", we can see that `num` sets the headlines that will be numbered: headline levels above this number will be unumbered.

> ‘num:’
>
> Toggle section-numbers (‘org-export-with-section-numbers’).  When
>       set to number ‘n’, Org numbers only those headlines at level ‘n’ or
>       above.  Setting ‘UNNUMBERED’ property to non-‘nil’ disables
>       numbering of a heading.  Since subheadings inherit from this
>       property, it affects their numbering, too.

What you want to change is the number of headline levels to use for export, and that is option `H`:

> ‘H:’
>
> Set the number of headline levels for export
>        (‘org-export-headline-levels’).  Below that level, headlines are
>        treated differently.  In most back-ends, they become list items.

So you should use the following setting:

```
#+OPTIONS: H:6
```

Note that the effect of this line is to set the value of variable `org-export-headline-levels` for this one buffer.  There are other ways to set this parameter:

> Export options can be set: globally with variables; for an individual
>   file by making variables buffer-local with in-buffer settings, by setting individual keywords, or by specifying
>   them in a compact form with the ‘#+OPTIONS’ keyword;

Comment: Gents, thanks all for helping. I was obviously suffering from a bad case of not reading properly.  The manual is pretty clear.  I did want to add a little more info about this problem I encountered.  You can set the H: option to whatever number you want.  However, @subsubsection is the lowest section command available in TexInfo.  So, if your Org file has headings level 5 or below and your H: option has something like H:5, the TexInfo will not compile.

Comment: @PabloAPerez-Fernandez You mean when you run makeinfo on it? Indeed, that might be considered a bug, as the texinfo is found incorrect.  In this case you may want to change your question to asking about the H:6 not working, it would surely be much more usefull for future readers (I would update my answer then).

Comment: yes, that is what I meant.  When one runs `MakeInfo buffer` on the texi file, you get the behavior I described.  However, I am not sure it should be considered a bug.  The manual does say that the `H:n` option forces the headers to be exported as such instead of enumerated lists up to the `n`-th level.  But, there is NO way for TexInfo to create such a deep section for headers `n>4`